# How to avoid Data Duplication in Parse iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

i am newbie in iOS with Parse i make an app that contain Facebook login i want to make if user is already login then i put its data in to my Parse Data table like as

```
PFObject *userInfo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"];
        userInfo[@"email"]=self.email;
        userInfo[@"name"]=self.username;
        [userInfo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
         {
             if (succeeded)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Do whatever you want to Do");
             }
             else{
                 NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
             }

         }];
```

But it contain duplicate data for every same user so i write a code for this like as

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:self.username];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",objects);
    if ([objects containsObject:self.username])
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", objects);
    }
    else
    {
        PFObject *userInfo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"];
        userInfo[@"email"]=self.email;
        userInfo[@"name"]=self.username;
        [userInfo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
         {
             if (succeeded)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Do whatever you want to Do");
             }
             else{
                 NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
             }

         }];
    }    }];
```

But it is Working same as above, Here i want to make if user is already login then its data was not inserted in to table for every time.
please give me solution for this.

Comment: Are you trying to not save a duplicate user or are you trying to not save a duplicate object? I'm confused about your example parse already has a user system that you don't need to manage manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but it seems like you are trying to create you own user object. I would user the built in one instead. Link to docs. Plus simple example of using it with facebook below. It doesn't include everything.
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-logging-in

```
NSArray *permissions = @[kLoginPermissionPublicProfile, kLoginPermissionEmail, kLoginPermissionFitness, kLoginPermissionBirthday];

if ([PFUser currentUser] == nil) {
    if(facebookSignin){
        [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            //Pull any facebook data and save it
        }];
    }else if(signUp){
        PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
        user.username = email;
        user.password = password;
        user.email = email;

        [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError* error){
            //add data and save it
        }];
    }else{
        [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:email password:password block:^(PFUser* user, NSError* error) {
            if (!error) {
                if (user) {
                    //add data and save it
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}else{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    user[@"phone"] = @"415-392-0202";
    [userInfo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        //ToDo
    }];
}
```